# How to use password from keyring in a script

Tags: password, gnome-keyring, password-store

I am sending mails with gmail authentication

```
swaks -tls -t --body -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -tls -a LOGIN \
-au my.google.username -ap <PASSWORD>
```

I don't want to have to enter my password  everytime I send a mail. I want it to be given once and forgotten after 1 hour.

**How do I save my password in my keyring in order to use it in my script (to be forgotten after a period of 1 hour ideally)?**

Thank you in advance